# SSRS Combine Multiple Rows into One

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm putting together an SSRS Report that will show what people owe for their membership dues.

Right now I get a few different rows per person depending on if they have Dues, Late Fees, or Refunds.

I need to be able to show these as one row instead of as three separate rows.

My list currently shows as:

```
Member ID | Name | Date | Dues | Refund | Late Fee | Inv ID | Total
123456789 | John | 2015 | $150 | ------ | -------- | INV 01 | $150
123456789 | John | 2015 | ---- | ------ | -----$10 | INV 01 |  $10
987654321 | Jane | 2015 | $150 | ------ | -------- | INV 02 | $150
```

What I'd like it to show as:

```
Member ID | Name | Date | Dues | Refund | Late Fee | Inv ID | Total
123456789 | John | 2015 | $150 | ------ | -----$10 | INV 01 | $160
987654321 | Jane | 2015 | $150 | ------ | -------- | INV 02 | $150
```

--Clarification--
Right now the only way to tell which an item is, is by the description of the item; i.e., the item name would be Membership Dues, or Membership Late Fee, or Membership Refund, which end up making the different line items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with the following SQL:

```
WITH cte_Intial AS (
    SELECT
        c.firstname
        ,c.lastname
        ,c.new_memberid
        ,s.new_invid
        ,CASE
            WHEN sd.productidname LIKE 'Late%' THEN NULL
            ELSE s.totalamount
        END AS "Dues"
        ,CASE
            WHEN sd.productidname LIKE 'Late%' THEN s.totalamount
            ELSE null
        END AS "LateFee"
        ,s.new_purchasedate
        ,s.name
        ,sd.productidname
    FROM
        Filteredcontact AS c
        INNER JOIN FilteredSalesOrder AS s ON c.new_memberid = s.new_memberid
        INNER JOIN FilteredSalesOrderDetail AS sd ON s.salesorderid = sd.salesorderid
    WHERE
        c.new_divisioncode = 'A' AND sd.productidname LIKE '%Dues%' AND
        DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(s.new_purchasedate AS DATE)) = 2015
)
SELECT
    firstname
    ,lastname
    ,new_memberid
    ,ISNULL(MAX(Invoice), '')/* + ' ' + ISNULL(MAX(Late), '')*/ as Invoice
    ,MAX(Dues) as Dues
    ,MAX(LateFee) as LateFee
    ,new_purchasedate
    ,name
FROM 
    cte_Intial
GROUP BY
    firstname
    ,lastname
    ,new_memberid
    ,new_purchasedate
    ,name
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to aggregate your data:

```
select member_id, name, date, sum(dues) dues
     , sum(refund) refund, sum(late_fee) late_fee
     , inv_id, sum(total) total
  from your_table
 group by member_id, name, date, inv_id;
```